# How to personalise menu links attributes

Tags: theming, 8, taxonomy-terms

I met some problem with my menu items on my site. All content of the page is given in the "title" attribute of the item, like this: http://joxi.ru/Q2K53V5H9WXyxr I think it's not pretty cool for SEO and users. How to clear such a large title attribute of link?
Used module: Taxonomy Menu
Core: Drupal 8

I think problem could be solved with themisation of the menu.html.twig, but I don't know how to.

Hope for your advice!